# Datanucleus, Is PMF thread save ? issue in tomcat

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

Do you know if PMF in datanucleus is thread safe ? I have following issue:
I have one PMF which creates several PersistenceManagers, one for method invocation. The PMF is share between threads and methods. 
Everyghing is ok when running application in single thread, but when app was deployed on Tomcat stress test shown that in some situation persistence managers were stack on simultanous getObjectById invocations. 
This is not a lock issue becasue the nontransactional read was on. The multithread flag was also set to true.
The problem disapeared when I created new PMF every time. But this solution is expensive.
Any ideas on better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

PMF is thread-safe as the JDO spec says very clearly. PM is not thread-safe and all DataNucleus docs advise on one PM per request. Since you (say you) have 1 PM per request then there is no prospect of locking  since the PM shares nothing with another PM.

If you say you have blocking you could easily provide a thread dump that shows how two PMs are locking each other, which then demonstrates what is blocking what and why. Possibilities ... L2 cache, store manager (datastore). Obviously using recent releases makes sense for all of that

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's strange that using different PMF solves the problem. I do not use L2 cache, datastore is MySql, i also use nontransactional read. In free time I revert the changes and try to analyze it (yeah....free time ;) )